# The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed. in codeigniter

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I have problem in upload files using codeigniter. I only set the file type to xls only for excel 2003 format only. In some computers uploading works perfectly but in some computers the problem exist "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed". I don't know why this problem occur since it's working in other computers.

Any idea about this problem??

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes occurred due to the encoding of file in different system,,, me also got this error, when i use a windows system it works perfectly for excel files. but in a linux system i got this error, files created with open office or other application having this issue, but xls file from ms office 2007 has no such issues in my side...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of CI you are using? If it's older one, then problem is because of CI Bug.
Check below link. It's because of mime setup in config for excel. Hope this will you to solve it.

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/394

Comment: then, did you check link?

Answer (score 0):

That is not CI issue.It happens due to different file encoding methods happen on different OS although the file format is same.

Comment: so what is your recommendations?